# Using egrep regex in subprocess python module

Tags: python-2.7, unix

I need help to grep a regex pattern using python subprocess module.

For e.g.

```
cmd = 'egrep "MEMBER xe-.* xe-.*" -h -o /home/temp.txt'

cmd_output,cmd_err = Popen(cmd.split(), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
```

I understand `*` doesn't expand with Popen and so I tried with `shell=True` as well but I am unable to get desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `shell=True`, you should supply the command as a string instead of a list:

```
cmd_output,cmd_err = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
```

When passing a list instead, it [won't do what you expect](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.

That said, it's probably easier, safer, more portable and more robust to just do this processing in Python instead. It has [excellent regex capabilities](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html), and the above translates to just a handful of lines of Python code.